# Does anyone know how to connect RabbitMQ with COBOL?

Tags: rabbitmq, cobol

Does anyone know how to connect RabbitMQ with COBOL? I tried the documentation in RabbitMQ site but the examples make calls to programs like "RMQ_CONNECT" that don't exists.

Comment: Taking a quick glance at the rabbitMQ documentation, I don't see anywhere that shows you how to do it in COBOL. Where did you get the info about RMQ_CONNECT?

Comment: In this site: http://assortedrambles.blogspot.pt/2013/04/using-rabbitmq-from-cobol_9584.html

Comment: based on that documentation, you are making a "homebrew" solution to call RabbitMQ. Chances are people here will not be able to help you because of how specific everything needs to be to work. If I had to guess, I would say that the API (written in C) is not in the right the place. Looks like a configuration issue on the surface and we can't really diagnose those.

Comment: do you know any place where can i find the program "RMQ_CONNECT" even in C?

Comment: No idea. I would try the RabbitMQ website, there's an installation guide on there.

Comment: The site mentions RabbitMQ for the server broker, rabbitmq-c library for providing access to it from C and a wrapper library (likely written in C) that provides the entry points `RMQ_CONNECT`, `RMQ_RPC_CALL`, `RMQ_STRERROR`, `RMQ_DISCONNECT`.
It does not link to this wrapper library but describes how it works. Therefore either contact the author for providing it or write it on your own.
Answer to the question "how to connect": directly call the C interface from rabbitmq-c (see its description) and you can do everything needed.

Comment: RabbitMQ also supports simple protocols, like STOMP

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, RMQ_CONNECT is not a program, but an entry point in a library.  Try using Call "RMQ_CONNECT" and make sure the rabbitMQ library is properly linked for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Write a c or c# helper exe that takes the payload on the command line and sends it to rabbit, then execute it with a "Call SYSTEM using command-line"

like this:

```
insert-mongodb-record.
move spaces to command
string "mongo --quiet --eval 'db.norple.insertOne({_id: """my-id""", age: """my-age""", initial:"""my-initial""","
  "description:"""trim(my-description)""", nimbus:"""my-nimbus"""})' cobol"
into command
display command
call "SYSTEM" using command end-call
exit paragraph
.
```